# Configure Gradle to include main classes as well as test classes into my .jar archive

Tags: build, gradle

How do I configure Gradle to include main classes as well as test classes into my .jar archive.  Currently the .jar that gets built in the **build/libs**  directory is missing my test classes.   It is only including classes sourced from **project-root/src/main/java/com/package**  in the .jar after Gradle compiles them into **project-root/bin/com/package/** .

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': title, 'Implementation-Version': version, 'Main-Class': mainTestClass
    }
}
```

The wierd thing is that while Gradle is putting the compiled test classes into **project-root/bin/com/package/** ALONG with the main classes, it strangely is deciding to not put them into the .jar archive.  So, how do I get the .jar to also include the test classes that were originally sourced in the  **project-root/src/test/java/com/package/**  directory?

[Here is my build.gradle file](https://gist.github.com/4108725) that I need help with.

Comment: Your gradle file looks like it includes quite a bit that you shouldn't need.  If using WebDriver with Gradle I'd also strongly recommend looking at Geb (http://www.gebish.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my code is pure Java and I don't really use Groovy in my project except that I use Gradle to build my project.  At your suggestion, I edited my build.gradle and removed a few lines from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N11E2A):

> The Java plugin defines two standard source sets, called main and test. The main source set contains your production source code, which is compiled and assembled into a JAR file. The test source set contains your unit test source code, which is compiled and executed using JUnit or TestNG.

It's highly suspect that you would want your tests in your jar, but adding them to the main source set would likely be the simplest solution.

Comment: My project is a JUnit Selenium project , which is why I might want it all in one .jar file.  I probably shouldn't have separate tests because the main project is "tests" in itself?

Comment: Yes, if the application is the tests then that should be the `main` source set.  If you create page objects or utility functions within the testing application, then you may want consider writing tests for those, and those tests should be in the `test` source set.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I reconfigured.  Here is my project:  https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate

Answer (score 1):

I use like this

```
task jarr(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.toSet().output
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'main.Mainn',
                "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ') + ' ' +
                        configurations.testRuntime.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ') + ' ' +
                        configurations.implementation.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Similarly, in the default `jar { ... }`, I added `from sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output`

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin DSL users, you may want to try the following which overrides the default jar task to include contents from the test source set:

```
tasks.jar {
    from(sourceSets["test"].output)
}
```