# Gradle giving mainClassName related error suddenly

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, gradle

I am using Java+Spring Boot+ Gradle+ Docker.
My spring boot application has suddenly started giving error "No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'. This was working fine just some days back.

I googled and added below to my gradle script:

```
mainClassName = 'com.test.MyMainClass'
```

Now the project gets build successfully but i am getting below error when running using docker.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.test.MyMainClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Below is my docker file:

```
FROM oraclejdk8:slim
ADD build/libs/MyTest.jar /MyTest.jar
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "/MyTest.jar" ]
```

I have googled but am unable to find any solution. Please help.

UPDATE 
I downloaded the jar and extracted it. I see it doesn't contain any of the classes from src/main/java. Thus the core issues is that my classes(which include  main class also) are not getting bundled in the jar.

This is strange as same code was working fine previously. Does anybody has any pointers.

I ran the gradle build on local machine(windows) and the build gets stuck at **bootRepackage** task. Below is the last log:

```
executing actions for task ':bootRepackage'.
02:42:47.123 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Setting mainClass: com.test.MyMainClass
 Building 81% : :bootRepackage
```

If I disable it then and run. the build completes and the jar contains my classes.

**Should I disable this bootRepackage task? Any help will be highly appreciated.**

The original issue came during jenkins build on linux.

Comment: Probably you are not adding the test in your jar. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446545/configure-gradle-to-include-main-classes-as-well-as-test-classes-into-my-jar-ar

Comment: I downloaded the jar and extracted it. I see it doesn't contain any of the classes from src/main/java. This is strange as same code was working fine previously. Does anybody has any pointers